# How to get value from selected icon dropdown?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 icons. i.e `icon-star`, `icon-check`, `icon-info`. if `icon-start` selected, then i want to store the value of the selected icon into database. for example:

- `icon-start` with `value="star"`
- `icon-check` with `value="complete"`
- `icon-info` with `value="important"`

So, the value stored into database is `"star"` because i choose `icon-star`.

Where i must put the value? and how?

**Here my modal:**

```
<form autocomplete="off" novalidate action="<?= base_url('app/admin/to-do-add')?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
    <div class="btn-group dropup dropdown-icon-wrapper mr-1 mb-1" style="float:right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="status">
            <i class="feather icon-star dropdown-icon"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <span class="dropdown-item">
                <i class="feather icon-star" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Starred" value="star"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown-item">
                <i class="feather icon-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Important" value="important"></i>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown-item">
                <i class="feather icon-check" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Completed" value="complete"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>To</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="select2 form-control" name="to">
                <option value="<?php echo $dataLogin->MEmployee_ID;?>">-SELECT-</option>
                <?php foreach ($data1 as $row){ ?>
                <option value=" <?php echo $row->MEmployee_ID ?>">
                    <?php echo $row->EmployeeName?>
                </option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?= $this->lang->line('add');?></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Here my controller :**

```
public function addTask(){
    var_dump($this->input->post('status')); die(); //i tried to var_dump, the value is NULL
    $dataLogin = $this->employee_model->checkUserData($this->session->userdata('islogin'))->row();
    $data = [
        "MEmployee_ID" => $this->input->post('to'),
        "status" => $this->input->post('status') //here the value of selected icon 
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am proposing a solution and it will work because I did it same and it worked.

1. (View) Take three checkbox input for   your three icons

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="start" value="start">
   <input type="checkbox" name="complete" value="complete">
   <input type="checkbox" name="important" value="important">
```

2. (Controller)

   [image]
3. (Model)
   define those three input default value type null

Try it I am here to help!

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image. Code should be included as text in the answer itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a "select" instead of a "dropdown" because a dropdown is not an input. And according to **ww3school** 
(https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)

> The select element defines a drop-down list.
>
> The option elements defines an option that can be selected.

I suggest you try this code:

```
<?php echo form_open('app/admin/to-do-add'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">

    <select class="custom-select mb-3" name="status">
        <option selected disabled>-- Status--</option>
        <option value="star"><i class="feather icon-star" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Starred" ></i></option>
        <option value="important"><i class="feather icon-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Important"></i></option>
        <option value="complete"><i class="feather icon-check" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Completed"></i></option>
    </select>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>To</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="select2 form-control" name="to">
                <option value="<?php echo $dataLogin->MEmployee_ID;?>">-SELECT-</option>
                <?php foreach ($data1 as $row){ ?>
                <option value=" <?php echo $row->MEmployee_ID ?>"><?php echo $row->EmployeeName?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?= $this->lang->line('add');?></button>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making a `hidden input field` and changing its `value` every time an icon is `clicked`. Here I'm using `hidden field name="icon"`, you can get it in your `controller` by `$this->input->post('icon');`, its default value is empty, you can change it to however you want.

```js
let icon_node = document.querySelectorAll('.feather'); // get all the elements with feather class(icons)

var icon_arr = [...icon_node]; // converts NodeList to Array

icon_arr.forEach(icon => {
  icon.addEventListener('click', item => { // add a click event on all elements with feather class
    
    let curr_value = icon.getAttribute("value"); // get value from value attribute
    document.querySelector('#icon').value = curr_value; // set value of hidden field

    console.clear();
    console.log(curr_value);
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <input type="hidden" id="icon" name="icon" value="" /> <!-- hidden field here -->
  <span class="dropdown-item">
    <i class="feather icon-star" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Starred" value="star">star</i> <!-- dummy text for test purpose -->
   </span>
  <span class="dropdown-item">
      <i class="feather icon-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Important" value="important">important</i> <!-- dummy text for test purpose -->
    </span>
  <span class="dropdown-item">
      <i class="feather icon-check" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Completed" value="complete">complete</i> <!-- dummy text for test purpose -->
    </span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.